# Employer has my federal taxes as exempt - W4

Tags: taxes

I just noticed my employer isn’t taking out federal taxes and has me as exempt. When I brought it to their attention they said I must’ve accidentally checked the exempt box on my W-4. However, it’s not a check box on the form, you have to write it in.

When I asked for a copy of my W-4 that I physically filled out when hired, they said the can’t find it and just fill out a new one.

What should I do? I’m going to owe the IRS.  I know I should have caught it earlier but I feel like it’s fraud on their part. I don’t know what to do.

Comment: This sounds like a clerical error, not fraud.

Comment: I know I should have been paying attention and shouldn’t use being young as an excuse but how is their clerical error my fault when I filled out my form correctly? I guess I’m just pissed because I didn’t catch it until late and it was their error and keep lying saying I checked the exempt box on the form. Guess I’ll look for another job.

Comment: Quitting is a rather petty response to this and won't solve anything. I think it is more likely that the error was yours since the person handling your form probably has had much more experience processing that form than you ever will in filling it out. If you cannot accept the possibility that you have some blame in situations like this, you're going to lead a very unhappy life.

Comment: Mr. Pierce, first of all the W-4 is straight forward for choosing exempt. You have to write “exempt” in box 7. I didn’t write it. Secondly, calling my choice to look for another job Petty is rather judgmental. Maybe I’m young and naive but I do have some integrity. I take my responsibility in not checking my pay stubs, however they can’t/won’t take responsibility for their error.

Comment: I don't understand how your integrity is jeopardized over taking responsibility for a clerical error. If they were asking you to act unethically, that would be a different story. I think the word you're looking for is hubris.

Comment: I guess I was expecting the HR/payroll person to take responsibility for their clerical error instead of blaming me for the clerical error. I just feel if you can’t be honest and truthful about the situation then it’s a integrity issue. You live, you learn.

Comment: If you decide to quit your job every time someone else fails to take responsibility for a mistake you think they made, you are going to spend a very large portion of your life searching for new jobs.

Comment: If you quit your job, you won’t be able to pay your taxes, which are due in April.  I hope you have since corrected the withholding issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't fraud. Any money they collect for taxes and social security and the like they are required to pass on by law to the proper authority. So there is no gain for them by accidentally entering your status as exempt.

When ever you need to change numbers on a federal or state W-4 just fill out and submit a new one, and then check your pay stubs to make sure they are correct.

Don't waste time trying to track down the old form before submitting a new form now so that no more checks are impacted.

Always review your stub to make sure it is correct. The stub should include the number of allowances you are claiming, or note you are exempt.

Your big problem is now that it is January, how long was it going on in 2017? If no federal taxes were collected at all you may owe a lot of money to the federal or state government. There may also be interest and penalties. I would see a tax professional now to understand what this means, and if there was any recourse. Also download all your pay stubs for 2017 to see if the change happened  mid-year.

Comment: Although I strongly agree with the advice to immediately submit a correct W4, it is still worth trying to track down the old one. Evidence that the non-collection was due to the employer's mistake may be useful to the OP's tax professional when negotiating with the IRS about penalties and, if necessary, a payment plan.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I’m going to owe and it’s going to be hard because I’m a college student and have rent & school to pay for. I think they know they messed up because they keep giving me the run around about the original W4. They have no proof that I even chose exempt at this point because they don’t have my original W4 in my file. It sucks. Adulting suck, lol!

Comment: It was your responsibility to verify that your employer was withholding the correct amount.  You should have also kept a copy for your own records.